# Jquery continuous slidedown issue

Tags: jquery

I have some code here: http://jsfiddle.net/zkRq2/2/  that I am having issues with.  If you go into the link area the div below will slide down just like it is supposed to.  The issue happens when you go from the link area then into the sliding down div area too fast.  When that happens the slideDown starts happening continuously.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It's two different areas with a gap between.  You trigger the animation queue twice by moving from one to the other before the first one completes.  `hover()` won't solve this issue but in general I've found it to be more reliable than using `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tell jQuery to start the animation only if no current animation is running on the element:

```
    $('.region-drop-down-menu').not(":animated").slideDown();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zkRq2/4/